# SQL single-group group function error/Not a group-by expression

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by

I'm trying to create a view, but when i include the "group by" function, it says that there is an error at line 2 saying that it is not a group-by expression.
If i comment out the "group-by" function, then it says theres an single-group group function error in the view.
how can i fix this?

```
CREATE or REPLACE VIEW bestseller_view
  AS SELECT e.empl_name,
            NVL((sum((si.amt_paid+a.ao_price)-fs.purchase_cost+a.ao_purchase_price)*se.salary_comm),0) sales_commission,
            COUNT(si.s_empl_id) vehicles_sold
 FROM for_sale fs
 JOIN sales_invoice si ON fs.vehicle_id = si.vehicle_id
 JOIN sales_empl se    ON si.s_empl_id = se.empl_id
 JOIN purchased_ao pao ON si.sales_invoice_id=pao.sales_invoice_id
 JOIN add_ons a        ON pao.ao_id=a.ao_id
 JOIN employee e       ON se.empl_id=e.empl_id;
 GROUP BY si.s_empl_id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-aggregate column in your `select` is `e.empl_name`, so you need to group by that, not `si.s_empl_id;`:

```
... SELECT e.empl_name,
  NVL((sum(...),0) sales_commission,
  COUNT(...) vehicles_sold
...
GROUP BY e.empl_name;
```

But since `empl_name` presumably isn't guaranteed to be unique, grouping by the ID makes more sense. You need to either select and group by both columns - though using `e.empl_id` might look more logical - and just ignore the ID you get back if it isn't relevant, in this case by just never selecting it from the view; or use this as an inner query and don't include it in the outer one. Seems like it makes more sense to have it in the view in case anyone does want/need it one day.

```
... SELECT e.empl_id, e.empl_name,
  NVL((sum(...),0) sales_commission,
  COUNT(...) vehicles_sold
...
GROUP BY e.empl_id, e.empl_name;
```

You also have your parentheses in the wrong place in your `sum`:

```
NVL((sum((si.amt_paid+a.ao_price)-fs.purchase_cost+a.ao_purchase_price)
     *se.salary_comm),0) sales_commission,
```

... is calculating  the sum of all the `(si.amt_paid+a.ao_price)-fs.purchase_cost+a.ao_purchase_price` values, and *then* multiplying that sum by the `se.salary_comm`, which makes that column non-aggregate as well; I'm pretty sure that's not what you meant to do, so that should be:

```
NVL(sum((si.amt_paid+a.ao_price-fs.purchase_cost+a.ao_purchase_price)
  *se.salary_comm),0) sales_commission,
```

Or if there is a one-to-one relationship between `e` and `se`, which looks likely, you could leave that as it is and add `se.salary_comm` to the `group by` clause as @ypercube suggested.

Comment: The `se.salary_comm` needs to be in the `GROUP BY` as well, it's not inside the `SUM()` aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT e.empl_name, si.s_empl_id
 ...
 GROUP BY e.empl_name, si.s_empl_id
```

Comment: I just tried that and got: ERROR at line 3: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: Sorry, that was not helpful.  What happens if you remove the GROUP By and add 'SELECT DISTINCT si.s_empl_id'